# SQL same class appears in table concurrently

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a SQL table with a "students" column and 5 "class" columns (Math, Reading, Writing, History, and English) to show what 5 courses each student is enrolled in.

This query relies on the fact that "Math" may be taken at the same time as "English":

**In SQL how do I figure out How many students listed in the student table are taking both classes concurrently?**

Comment: Can you show some sample data and also what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think this question needs more clarification.  What values are you expecting in the "class" columns?  Are these Boolean fields? Varchar?

Comment: Probably not relevant, but you should nevertheless add the tag for the DBMS you are using - `postgresql`, `oracle`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the classes columns set as boolean then you would do something like this:

```
Select * from Table where Math=true and English=true
```

This will give you the list of people. If you just want the number of students then use:

```
Select count(*) from Table where Math=true and English=true
```

Hope this helps